# Using printf to print the value in the bx register (assembly language)

Tags: assembly, stack, printf

I'm attempting to print out the contents of the `bx register`.

`print_str` is defined earlier as:

```
    print_str:  db "Result: %d", 10, 0
```

When I pop `bx` in `debugger`, I see that `3` is put into `bx`. However after the call to `printf`, I get the `output "Result: 196611"`

```
    pop  bx
    push eax
    push bx     ; substitute with whatever you want to print
    push print_str    ; defined in the .data section
    call printf
    add esp, 8  ; pop the Msg and number off the stack
    pop eax     ; restore the value in eax that we stashed
```

Edit: When I replace `push bx` with `push 3`, it will `print "Result: 3"` so I don't get what is going wrong with saying `push bx` :(

Comment: You probably need to push a 32-bit value. Clear the upper 16 bits of `ebx` and then push `ebx` as the argument instead of `bx`.

Answer (score 1):

If you `push bx` you push a 16-bit value to the stack. It is not converted to a 32-bit value and the stack is decremented only by 2 (two bytes). It seems that you use a 32-bit C-library where `printf` expects 32-bit values on the stack. So `printf` will take `BX` **and** a part of the formerly pushed `EAX`.

Expand `BX` to `EBX` and push `EBX`:

```
movsx ebx, bx
push ebx
```